# ssh between client and server : How does server decrypt the data send by client to it?

Tags: encryption, ssh, private-key, public-key

I am trying to understand SSH mechanics; as I understand, using ssh we can secure connection between a client and server.

A client will create private and public key (say using ssh-keygen); pass on public key to server.

Now, we have this flow:

**Client -> Server**; the client has both pair of keys, so if server sends data (which is being encrypted by public key, then the client can decrypt it); but how does server decrypt the data which is being sent from the client -> server; the client will use the public key to encrypt the data; since the server has only the public key, how does it decrypt the data which client sends to it?

**Server -> Client**; the server has only public key; so I think this is ok; the server will use the public key to encrypt the data, and then a client will use its private key to decrypt the data.

Comment: The key that you generate with ssh-keygen is used to authenticate. It's not used to encrypt the data stream between the client and server. In any event, this question is pretty broad in its current form. If you want to understand how ssh encrypts its session, you should start with the ssh wikipedia page and the RFCs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but how does server decrypt the data which is being sent from the client -> server

Because after the server is verified, both the parties negotiate a session key using a version of something called the [Diffie-Hellman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).
This algorithm is designed in such a way that both the parties contribute equally in generation of session key.
The generated session key is shared symmetric key i.e. the same key is used for encryption and decryption.

See more at "[Understanding SSH workflow](https://medium.com/@Magical_Mudit/understanding-ssh-workflow-66a0e8d4bf65)" from **[Mudit Maheshwari](https://twitter.com/Magical_Mudit)**

And "[SSH (Key gen)](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/ssh)":

[image: https://asecuritysite.com/public/ssh01.png]